# Odd PHP header() behavior from POST to php_self - inconsistent across environments

Tags: php, post, header, include

I'm having a problem with sending back header(location:) as a response from an HTML form POST to PHP_SELF.

The essential parts of the use case:

- I'm including inside the main page, a
  page which contains all of the form
  UI echoed out.  This form POSTs to
  itself ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).
- This form contains a "file" field and
  passes some text (login, password,
  etc) to itself to do an FTP upload.
- If the upload is successful, I output
  header() where location is the main
  page (along with some parameters
  which tells the containing page to
  print a successful upload message).
- The main page (upon receiving the
  header) *should* display the include
  with the form echoed out again for
  the next upload.
- Everything works just as expected in
  Dev, but in Prod, I never get my form
  back - it's like the header isn't
  getting sent.

The three things that have made this so mysterious:

- I have two environments, dev is
  windows/apache 1.3.37/php 5.2.11 fast
  cgi, prod is linux/apache
  (2.2.16)/php 5.2.14 fast cgi, and
  I've configured as much of the
  relevant looking PHP params the same
  across both dev and prod.  In Dev,
  the aforementioned use case works
  great.  In Prod, the file does
  upload, but it's as though the header
  is not getting sent back.  The block
  where the included content should be
  is completely empty.
- If I separate the include so that the
  form content (the UI stuff) is the
  only thing in the include, and the
  form POSTs to a separate file which
  contains the FTP upload logic, the
  header sent back at the completion of
  a successful upload does work in both
  dev and prod...the file uploads, the
  header gets sent back, the main page
  refreshes, and the contents of the
  include are displayed.
- In Dev, through Fiddler, I can see
  the POST to PHP_SELF with all the
  form content, and I clearly see the
  header returned back.  In Prod, I can
  see the POST to PHP_SELF, everything
  looks good, but there is never a
  header returned returned back. 
  However, in debugging, headers_sent
  told me the header was being sent to
  the right location.  Echo'ing headers_sent shows up in my main page.

Extra trivia:

- I thought at first, .htaccess was
  getting in the way, but again,
  everything works if I split out the
  UI and FTP upload stuff, and
  .htaccess in this environment is very
  basic.
- I also thought, maybe output
  buffering would change the behavior -
  I tried ob_start in a variety of
  logical places, behavior never
  changed.
- Lastly, I tried a number options in
  header location - in some cases, just
  pointing to http://www.google.com -
  still it's as though no header is
  being sent at all.

I'm out of ideas - can someone offer some direction on this??

Here is a simplified test case - which, interestingly enough, behaves the same in dev as prod, so at least it's consistent now.

- Test.php is included in a page called "upload.php" with a couple of buttons rendered.
- "Try" POSTs to PHP_SELF and the
  rendered contents of test.php never
  come back when header('Location:
  ./upload.php') is
  called...the space in the including
  page is blank.
- However, "Try2" POSTs to test2.php
  which calls header('Location:
  ./upload.php') and re-renders the
  buttons of the included test.php page
  no problem.

Here is a test.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']) {
Header('Location: ./upload.php');
} else {
echo
'<form name="test" action="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'" method="POST">
<input type=submit value=try name=submit>
</form>
<form name="test2" action="test2.php" method="POST">
<input type=submit value=try2 name=submit>
</form>';
}
?>
```

and here is test.php...pretty simple.

```
<?php
Header('Location: ./upload.php');
?>
```

and here is a snippet from upload.php:

```
<!--    <div id="flashcontent"></div> -->
</fieldset><?php require_once('test.php'); ?></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Today's update - in fact, the behavior of the simple test case was not as I originally thought.  I was already including the real-life file above the simple test case include which I think was resulting in the classic headers-already-sent problem.  Once I commented out the real-life file, the behavior of the simple test case now matches the original case outlined at the start of this post.  So, the simple test case loads the header if called from within the include on form submit, and loads the header if called from another page posted-to from the included file...no problem.  However, in production, the results of the header call are only realized if called from a page posted-to, and not if called when posting to php_self.

```
<div class="panel_wrapper">
<div id="general_panel" class="panel currentmod">
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo TB_UPLOADFILES; ?></legend>
<?php
//define('upload_opt',TRUE);
//require_once('upload_opt.php');
?>
<!--    <div id="flashcontent"></div> -->
</fieldset><?php require_once('test.php'); ?></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oddly, I'm not finding anything useful or relevant in logging (Apache or PHP) - and now that I have a test case that behaves the same in both environments, it makes me think that it is something which is best avoided from a coding point of view??  i.e.: don't call header() for the including page from the page that's included?

Comment: According to HTTP 1.1 specs, Location header should use absolute URI (including domain and protocol)

Comment: Yes, and even with testing with 'Location: http://www.google.com', the results are the same...

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the header is being sent after an error. Try turning errors off on the production server.

Also check that no white space is being output before the header.

File names in Linux are case sensitive, so make sure your cases are correct too. If it can't find the new location, that could do the trick (although I doubt this, because google.com didn't work.)

Try adding "exit()" after the header declaration.

Make sure your header has the correct syntax and is absolute if the resource is external.

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
exit();
```

Try doing a dumbed down example on your production server to test. Remove the post altogether and make sure header redirects are working. It could be a restricted function if you are using a shared host and aren't in control of the PHP.ini file.

If none of those work, a snippet of your header code would be interesting to look at.

Comment: Thanks James - I gave exit() a shot, still no good.  Case sensitivity - checked and double checked.  Simple use case...should have done this right from the start.  My edits show the results of the simple use case - and interestingly, now the behavior is the same in both dev and prod.  I'm beginning to think that my approach is flawed - calling header for the including page from the page that is included - it's almost logical that this could be problematic...does anybody know for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, this all has to do with output order, buffering and headers, and is ultimately *solved* using output buffering (ob_start / ob_end_flush).  Despite the fact that output buffering is set the same in both environments (output_buffering: 4096), for some reason, I seem to be enjoying the buffering in Dev that I'm not in Prod.  By wrapping the including page in ob_start() and ob_end_flush(), the behavior is now consistent and as-desired in both environments.

I'm not thrilled about this as it seems a workaround, and I still don't have a clue as to why the behavior is different across the two environments.  It seems the more sure solution would be not to POST to PHP_SELF to call header(Location), but to POST to another file which calls header(Location).  Somewhere, it's probably written that this is best practice, don't try to call header(Location) from within, and avoid the use of output buffering.

Should anyone want to really dig into this mystery, feel free to [contact me offline](http://www.PigsLipstick.com) because I've managed to fix the symptoms, but I still don't know what the problem is.